# Is there any code for wifi-direct group chat (3 devices)

Tags: android, wifi-direct

i need to implement p2p chat with multiple clients.  means 1 server multiple clients(1 to many)
1group owner--->client1
           |----client2
           |---->client3
           |---->client4

Comment: right, what have you done so far?

Comment: I have only Android--->Samples WifiDemoActivity code. which is file transferring

Answer (score 1):

Android sdk has a wifi-direct Demo, named "WifiDirectDemo"

Answer (score 0):

You can try with some interesting links:

https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/peer-peer-alljoyn

https://developers.google.com/talk/libjingle/important_concepts

https://github.com/hmrtk/p2p-dht-simple-protocol-implementation

Good luck!